# Protecting my php script/mysql query from SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

I just realized that the php script I use to pull mySQL data and display it on website is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. What practices are used to protect against these attacks?

Comment: Look at http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for examples of how to use parametrized queries in PHP.  See also http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

Using `mysqli_real_escape_string` to escape whatever is going in is the least you should be doing.

You might also want to look into using prepared statements.

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Please do *not* use string escaping.  The wise PHP programmer will use parametrized queries.

Comment: I said it is the least he should be doing, there are obviously better methods such as parametrizing and using prepared statements.

Comment: Not to mention that prepared statements aren't available everywhere (read: `mysql_*`), and yes, I know developers shouldn't be using that set of functions, but the reality is that we are.

Answer (score 0):

All the comments to your post are good suggestions. I personally prefer using prepared statements through [PHP's PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Every parameter you get from the user (whether direct or indirect), every value you you insert into your query from a variable you didn't explicitly set, etc, should be inserted into your queries using prepared statements. No exceptions. More experienced developers can get away with a few exceptions, but I would recommend no exceptions, ever.

See [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) in the PHP documentation for some examples.